# C++ How to copy pointer data ( and all of its systems ) to another pointer of the same type?

Tags: c++, pointers

It's easier for me to explain this kind of stuff in videogame terms. I'll try to be as clear as possible please bear with me...

I have a **Bullet** class that's made of different components, such as a Sprite component and a Transform Component... It would look something like this:

```
class Bullet
{
      public:
          Bullet( texture2D texture, Rectangle sourceRectangle, Rectangle destinationRectangle )
          Bullet();
          ~Bullet();

          // Returns a pointer to its sprite component so that I can use it wherever I want in the scene:
          Sprite* const Sprite() const{ return this->sprite; } 

          // Setters:
          void SetAngle( float new_angle ){ this->angle = new_angle; }
          void SetSpeed( float new_speed ){ this->speed = new_speed; }
          void SetRadius( float new_radius ){ this->radius = new_radius; }

     private:
         // Sprite component:
         Sprite* sprite;

    private:
        // Regular member data:
        float angle;
        float speed;
        float radius;
};
```

The sprite component is simply another class that holds a *texture*, *source rectangle*, *destination rectangle*, and some member functions to manipulate it (Move, Rotate, SetTexture, etc ). Nothing really special. It gets initialized within the constructor

What I need to do is to be able to copy one pointer to a bullet object entirely to another new pointer to a bullet, including the sprite component. Something like this:

```
// These arguments will be "fed" into the sprite component
Bullet* bullet1 = new Bullet( texture, sourceRect, destRect );
Bullet* bullet2 = new Bullet(); // Using default constructor.
*bullet2 = *bullet1;
```

Technically, doing it this way works. However, only the regular member data gets copied I think, but not the sprite component. It only points to the first bullet's sprite component. At least that's what I think is happening.

Hopefully I was clear explaining this issue, Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Make a copy constructor. Don't just slam it like this. Also worth noting: Try and avoid `new`. Memory management is a huge hassle. Pointers are trouble that you should try to avoid, or at least wrap in things like `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: If you want to share the same `Sprite` data over all the `Bulltet` instances, you shouldn't copy the data at  all. To solve the arising memeory management problems for such cases, c++ provides the `std::shared_ptr<T>` class, where `T` would be `Sprite` in your case.

Comment: Copy-constructors (as mentioned) might be a good start as then you can do `Bulle* bullet2 = new Bullet(*bullet1);`. For assignment you need a copy-*assignment* operator overload.

Comment: And please think about the *ownership* of the sprite. Will there ever be only a single sprite that can be shared? Then use `std::shared_ptr` and follow [the rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero). Otherwise if each `Bullet` really need its own unique sprite object, then use `std::unique_ptr` and follow [the rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_five) (though you won't need a destructor so the rule of four perhaps?)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll keep in mind everything you said, I appreciate it